# How to nest models with Generic Foreign Keys in Django?

Tags: python, django, nested

I’m doing my first Django project that’s not a tutorial and I thought it’d be a good learning experience to try and build a reddit-like site. So I have a Link model and a Comment model. The Comment model has a GenericForeignKey because it can refer to either a Link, or another Comment. I would like the comments to be able to nest under each other, but I’m at a loss as to how. Anyone have any ideas?

[This is the project](https://github.com/Flobin/parrot) and here’s models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

# Create your models here.
class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def score(self):
        return self.upvotes - self.downvotes

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def score(self):
        return self.upvotes - self.downvotes
```

edit: I wrote [this test](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/7d2812e41201b8e696a0) and it passes, which leads me to believe that comments can in fact nest. The question, then, is how do I make them nest in the view? My views file is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

from .models import Link, Comment
from .forms import LinkForm, CommentForm

# Create your views here.
def links(request):
    links = Link.objects.all().order_by('-posted')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = LinkForm(data=request.POST,auto_id=True)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.full_clean()
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/?next=/')
    else:
        form = LinkForm(auto_id=True)
    return render(request, 'posts/links.html', {'links': links, 'form': form})

def comments(request, link_id):
    link = get_object_or_404(Link, pk=link_id)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(
        object_id = link.id,
        content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(link)
    ).order_by('-posted')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            form = CommentForm(data=request.POST,auto_id=True)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.full_clean()
                form.save()
                return reverse('comments', kwargs={'link_id':link.id})
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login/?next=/{0}/'.format(link.id))
    else:
        form = CommentForm(auto_id=True)
        return render(request, 'posts/comments.html', {'comments': comments, 'link': link, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `django-mptt` to deal with this problem.

You can simply create a foreign key to the comment itself and then leave the rest job to `mptt`

You'll have to do something like this:

```
from mptt.models import TreeForeignKey, MPTTModel

class Comment(MPTTModel):
    ....
    ....
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', related_name='children',
                            blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

read docs @ [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But wouldn't having the foreign key refer to the comment itself disable the comment to have a link as its parent? I mean, this would allow a comment nest under another comment, but a set of comments also needs to refer to a particular link, right?

Comment: If you try to use the comment as it's own `GenericForeignKey`, it will be a bad implementation IMO. A comment is bound to have a parent `Link`, if you're thinking to populate the `gfk` with comment then how will you determine which nested comment is for which post? What I will do is simply add a `foreignkey` to `Link` and allow comments to have both, `Link` and `parent` comments, so i can simply call for `comments under this link` then let `mptt` do the comment nesting for me.

Comment: Thanks! This technically maybe didn't answer my question, but it did help solve my problem!